# How to extend the Swift SDK generated by AWS API Gateway?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-api-gateway

My Xcode project has 2 targets: an app and a static library. The library contains a Swift SDK generated by AWS API Gateway for a REST API, and extends it with some extra features. It builds just fine.

The library is linked to the app in the build settings and is referenced in the app code. The app also builds just fine.

The app crashes immediately when I run it, producing the following error log:

> dyld[21035]: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSAPIGateway.framework/AWSAPIGateway

It appears to be looking for the framework in several directories under: *Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*, though I do not know why since the app target does not depend on AWSAPIGateway directly.

Here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'lib' do
    pod 'AWSAPIGateway', '~> 2.6.35'
end
```

Any idea what the problem is here?

Comment: The app crashes using a simulator as well as a physical device.